# Android BroadcastReceiver not detecting SMS

Tags: java, android

I don't know what has gone wrong, but I'm having a difficult time with this one. The program is supposed to show a toast once a message is received. I have tried adding the priority in the manifest file, but it doesn't work.

The manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.comfy.textforwarder">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settings" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("RECEIVE", "Receiving SMS");
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if(intentExtras != null){
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get("pdus");
            String msgStr = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i){
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                String smsBoddeh = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String addr = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                msgStr += "SMS From " + addr + "\n";
                msgStr += smsBoddeh + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("RECEIVE", msgStr);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the permission?

Comment: If you forgot to add the permissions here it's add it in the manifest file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

Comment: Standard Qs: 1) Do you have the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission listed in the manifest outside of the `<application>` tags? 2) If you're running on API 23+ with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or above, are you handling the runtime permission correctly? 3) If you're running on a version prior to KitKat, are you sure another app isn't intercepting and aborting the broadcast? 4) Are you sure the `name` attribute on the `<receiver>` is pointing to the right class, in the right place? 5) Are you launching an `Activity` in your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state?

Comment: Is Log.d("RECEIVE", "Receiving SMS"); statement in the onReceive() executing?

Comment: I apologize for replying late, and yes, sir @MikeM. have added those permissions. I am using API 24 and phone's running on Kitkat. I should note that I am also using an 3rd party SMS app. And what do you mean by the `<receiver>` in the right place?

Comment: Mr. @SamuelRobert, the Log.d isn't executing.

Comment: For that manifest entry, your Receiver needs to be in its own class file that is in the same folder/package as `MainActivity`. Oh, and I just realized that you have the `<receiver>` disabled. Either change its `enabled` attribute to `true`, or just remove it, as it's enabled by default.

Comment: Change the enabled status to true in the manifest file under receiver tag

Comment: Solved below now... It was about the enabled status being false :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the same..

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.smsforwarder.smsforwarder.SMSReceiver"
    **android:enabled="true">**
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```